# Error: Invalid Alias or Id for SFDX Package Install

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, vs-code, visualstudiocode, sfdx-error

Getting error when using package alias name `sf package install provutil@1.26.0-1-06DEC2023` vs 04t Id. Using the Id works fine. My packages are namespaced.

> Error (1): Invalid alias or ID: provutil@1.26.0.1-06DEC2023.
> Either your alias is invalid or undefined, or the ID (04t) provided is
> invalid.

My `sfdx-project.json` has the below:

`"packageAliases": {   "provutil": "0Ho3w######",  "provutil@1.26.0-1-06DEC2023": "04tQK#####"   }`